# Automatic replies do not reply to the `replyTo` field. Nodemailer

Tags: nodemailer

I've been using nodemailer for emails from my application, and everything has been great. The one thing that I have found to be not working, and I may just be doing it wrong, is that when I set the `replyTo` property on the email message, that if the recipient has an automatic reply set up (i.e., for an out-of-office reply) it replies to the `from` and not the `replyTo`. However, manually clicking reply in the message does adhere to the `replyTo` field.

Example...

My app sends an email to `user2` from `myApp` that `user1` has tried to contact them in the app. If `user2` clicks reply to the email message they will send a direct email to `user1`. `user1@gmail.com`. This works great. Now, if `user2` has an automatic reply set up saying he/she is out of office, then the reply goes to `me@myApp.com`.

Any ways around this?